# Use Android phone as multi-boot usb

Tags: multi-boot, android

I have a usb key that I use quite often. I have loaded Yumi on it and use it to boot various live cd's and tools on the PC's that I am troubleshooting. I carry it pretty much everywhere I go. I also carry my Android phone everywhere I go, and it has a 32 GB sd card in it. I would like to be able to use the sd card and a USB cable just as I have used the USB key in the past.

Has anyone figured out how to boot from an image on an SD card?

Answer (score 1):

Try DriveDroid https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid

I've used it to boot Live Ubuntu, Ultimate Boot CD "UBCD" and Trinity Rescue. When I used it, it didn't allow booting using UEFI. That may have changed now.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether or not this works?